# How to get audio samples in linphone to pass to other interface or to save them?

Tags: c, audio, sip, voip, linphone

i am using `linphone-3.7.0` in `imx6 board`, the board contains telephony module. Landline telephone is connected with the board via `RJ11`.

Here i wanted to pass the audio samples to telephony module so that it will pass those audio samples to landline telephone.

From the source code of the `linphone` can u suggest me from where can i get the audio samples in the code as the source code is very huge?